# Restrict access to tomcat by Connector or RemoteAddrValve?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8

I want to restrict access to tomcat to only `localhost` and my internal network `192.168.*`.

Question: should I use the `<Connector` therefore, or the `<Context .. <Valve>` fields?

Either:

```
    <Context>
         <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
                allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1|192\.168\..*"/>
    </Context>
```

Or:

```
<Connector port="8080" address="127.0.0.1" .../>
<Connector port="8009" address="127.0.0.1" .../>
<Connector port="8080" address="192.168." .../>
<Connector port="8009" address="192.168." .../>
```

Both could work. Which which cases should you prefer one over the other?

Comment: `what should be preferred`, if they both work, and you can't decide, you need to provide more information

Comment: Then let me rephrase the question: in which case should I prefer one over the other solution?